# Sum of list elements in a range

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have a list, for example:

```
data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

and I wanted to sum every element in range of five, i. e

ranges

`{1,2,3,4,5}` and `{6,7,8,9,10}` and `{11,12,13,14,15}` and `{16,17,18,19,20}`

and the result I want to get is:

```
{34, 38, 42, 46, 50}
```

Comment: Try `Total[Partition[data, 5], {1}]`

Comment: Or `Total@GatherBy[data, Floor[(# - 1)/5] &]`

Comment: Or `Plus @@@ Transpose@Partition[data, 5]`.

Comment: Oof.  Lemme get a valid one in: `Plus@@data[[#;;;;5]]&/@Range@5`

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUajS.png) can be found under the `Details and Options` for `Total`.

Comment: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20} // Partition[#,5]& // MapThread[Plus]`

Comment: There are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing in Mathematica. I count only 8 ways so far in comments and answer(s) :)

Comment: @Nasser [`please?`](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/73494455/do-i-get-a-cookie.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **There are three ways that yield the desired outut: 1. [`Last@Accumulate@list`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) [`Plus@@list`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) and [`Total@list`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)**

---

**Various approaches to get the `list` mentioned above**

---

### **0. [`` Internal`PartitionRagged ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions)**

```
Last@Accumulate@
  Internal`PartitionRagged[data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

also

```
Plus @@ Internal`PartitionRagged[data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

and

```
Total@Internal`PartitionRagged[data, 
   Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

---

### **1. [`ArrayReshape`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html)**

```
Last@Accumulate@ArrayReshape[data, {Length@data/5, 5}]
```

also

```
Plus @@ ArrayReshape[data, {Length@data/5, 5}]
```

and

```
Total@ArrayReshape[data, {Length@data/5, 5}]
```

---

### **2. [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) + [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) + [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)**

```
Last@Accumulate@
  Fold[Partition, Flatten[data], {Length@data/5, 5}[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]]
```

also

```
Plus @@ Fold[Partition, 
  Flatten[data], {Length@data/5, 5}[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]]
```

and

```
Total@Fold[Partition, 
  Flatten[data], {Length@data/5, 5}[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]]
```

---

### **3. [`TakeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html)**

```
Last@Accumulate@TakeList[data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

also

```
Plus @@ TakeList[data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

and

```
Total@TakeList[data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

---

### **4. [`FoldPairList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) + [`TakeDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop.html)**

```
Last@Accumulate@FoldPairList[TakeDrop, data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

also

```
Plus @@ FoldPairList[TakeDrop, data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

and

```
Total@FoldPairList[TakeDrop, data, Table[5, Length@data/5]]
```

---

All of the above and the solutions suggested in the comments section give

> [image: lisres]

*I will update the timings later tonight*

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Range[20];
```

Using `MovingMap`:

```
Total@MovingMap[# &, data, 4][[1 ;; -1 ;; 5]]

(*{34, 38, 42, 46, 50}*)
```

Or using `BlockMap`:

```
Total@BlockMap[# &, data, 5]

(*(*{34, 38, 42, 46, 50}*)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Range[20];
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
Total @ SequenceCases[data, {Repeated[_, {5}]}]
```

{34, 38, 42, 46, 50}

```
Total @ SequenceCases[data, _?(Length[#] == 5 &)]
```

{34, 38, 42, 46, 50}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ArrayReduce` and `Partition`:**

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
    19, 20};

Partition[data, 5] // ArrayReduce[Total, #, 1] &
```

---

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
MapThread[Plus@## &, Partition[data, 5]]
```

---

*Result:*

> {34, 38, 42, 46, 50}